# How would you maintain TCP connection in an IRC client app?

Tags: android, sockets

I'm trying to make an IRC client app as a learning experience and need advice on how to handle network connections.

Should I open a socket in a background task and make it listen for responses from the server? And then I receive a message the background thread sends data to the main activity, it will update the view. Is this the right way to do it?

I want to stop the background thread when the phone goes to sleep or the main activity closes.

I'm just looking for advice on what my options are and the recommended approach.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I would use a Service for the connection, sending a LocalBroadcast for new messages which is then intercepted by the activity. Creating the service in onCreate and stopping it in onDestroy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the reason for a listening socket. Your client will open the TCP connection to the server and all the communication to and from the server can run over this connection.

The rest looks ok to me, but I've only played a little with android programming. But you have to separate the communication part from the GUI, as you described. Otherwise the GUI could get blocked by the communication.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI or to anyone reading this, I'm searching for a more thorough answer since sometimes my bots will D/C, but the general jist is that you have to respond to "ping"s from the IRC servers with "pong"s or else it will force close your connection over time.  This differs across each network, I think.